# get Image from Pageproperties into an HMENU

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have an HMENU in Typo3, in the Pageproperties i have stored an image. How can i show the Image from the Pageproperties in ne Menu? I have no Idea, why the image is not displayed.
Typo3 6.2

```
lib.produkt_start = HMENU
lib.produkt_start {
  special = directory
  special.value = 3
  wrap = |
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    expAll = 1
    NO = 1
    NO {
      allWrap = <div class="patterns col4" id="page_{field:uid}">|</div>
      allWrap.insertData = 1
      ATagParams = id="uid{field:uid}"
      ATagParams.insertData = 1  
      stdWrap.cObject >
      stdWrap.cObject = COA
      stdWrap.wrap = |
      stdWrap.cObject {
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = title
        10.wrap = <br /><h2>|</h2>
        10.insertData = 1 
        20 = TEXT
        20.wrap =  <p><span>|</span></p>
        20.field = subtitle
        30 = IMAGE
        30.file.import.data = levelmedia-1, slide
        30.treatIdAsReference = 1
        30.import.listNum = 0
        30.wrap = <h5>|</h5>
      }
    }
    ACT = 1
    ACT < .NO

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your problem with TYPO3 6.1.7

First of all you have to correct you code a little:

```
[...]
      stdWrap.cObject {
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = title
        10.wrap = <br /><h2>|</h2>
        10.insertData = 1 
        20 = TEXT
        20.wrap =  <p><span>|</span></p>
        20.field = subtitle
        30 = IMAGE
        30.file.import.data = levelmedia:-1, slide
        30.file.treatIdAsReference = 1
        30.file.import.listNum = 0
        30.wrap = <h5>|</h5>
      }
[...]
```

Now it will be "working" but only if you actually set an image in media field of the parent page, then it will be renderd in all child pages, ignoring the fact that the child pages have an own image set - I would consider this as sort of a bug of TMENU or TMENUITEM, but I haven't realy testet it fully.

You will get a problem with entity encoding of the title as well so I would try this option:

```
  stdWrap.wrap.cObject = COA
  stdWrap.wrap.cObject {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = <br><h2>|</h2> 
    20 = TEXT
    20.wrap =  <p><span>|</span></p>
    20.field = subtitle            
    30 = IMAGE
    30.file.import.data = levelmedia:-1, slide
    30.file.treatIdAsReference = 1
    30.file.import.listNum = 0
  }
```

Strange is that the following does not work either:

```
30.file.import.field = media
```

This makes my suspition of the wrong slide behaviour above being a bug even stronger.